# Cannot disable EditText and score variable not updating

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm learning to build apps for Android by making a trivia app with 3 questions: 1 using radio buttons, 1 free text field, 1 with checkboxes.

The logic is that once a user chooses or enters an answer, the radio buttons, checkboxes and EditText will be grayed out, then the user will click on the score button to get a Toast with the score and a custom message.

I have 2 problems:

(1) The EditText doesn't gray out - I have tried multiple variations using `setFocusable()` and `setEnabled()` to no avail.

(2) The score variable doesn't assign question 2 (the one with the EditText) 1 point even when the answer entered is correct.

I have started over from scratch but I haven't been able to fix these things. Any leads?

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#fefcf1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/seinfeld_trivia_logo"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Who are the 4 main characters?"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/question_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Jerry, Elaine, George, Kessler"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonQ1Clicked"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_two"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Jerry, Elaine, George, Kramer"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonQ1Clicked"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_three"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Newman, Jerry, Kramer, George"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonQ1Clicked"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="What is Kramer's given name?"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/question_two_answer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onQ2AnswerEntered"
                android:enabled="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="What is correct about Festivus? Check all that apply."
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/question_three_answer_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="There is an aluminum pole"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="onCheckBoxesQ3Clicked"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/question_three_answer_two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="You eat ham"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="onCheckBoxesQ3Clicked"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/question_three_answer_three"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="You air your grievances"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="onCheckBoxesQ3Clicked"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reset_me"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#03A9F4"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="Try Again"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:onClick="resetQuiz"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score_me"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#03A9F4"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="Show me my score"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:onClick="showScoreMessage"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**My Java**

```
package com.example.android.seinfeldtrivia;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaring variables - Question 1
    RadioButton Q1A1, Q1A2, Q1A3;
    RadioGroup Q1RadioGroup;

    //Declaring variables - Question 2
    EditText Q2AnswerEditText;

    //Declaring variable for extracting the string from the EditText on Q2
    String question2Answer;

    //Declaring variables - Question 3
    CheckBox Q3A1, Q3A2, Q3A3;

    //Declaring variables to check the state of the checkboxes on Q3
    boolean checkedQ3A1, checkedQ3A2, checkedQ3A3;

    //Declaring variable - Score
    int score;

    //Declaring variable for the score and reset button
    Button scoreMe, resetQuiz;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing views - Question 1
        Q1RadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_1);
        Q1A1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_one);
        Q1A2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_two);
        Q1A3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_three);

        //Initializing views - Question 2
        Q2AnswerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_two_answer);

        //Initializing views - Question 3
        Q3A1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_answer_one);
        Q3A2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_answer_two);
        Q3A3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_answer_three);

        //Initializing views - Score & Reset buttons
        scoreMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score_me);
        resetQuiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_me);

    }

    //To disable the radio groups once the user has chosen an answer
    public static void enableQuestion(View view, boolean enabled) {
        view.setEnabled(enabled);
        view.setFocusable(enabled);

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++)
                enableQuestion(vg.getChildAt(i), enabled);
        }
    }

    //Getting the values of the answers entered
    /*
     * Checking which answer was selected - Question 1
     */
    public void onRadioButtonQ1Clicked(View view) {
        // Check that the user chose an answer
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_one_answer_one:
                if (checked) {
                    yourAnswerQ1 = Q1A1;
                    enableQuestion(Q1RadioGroup, false);
                    break;
                }
            //Correct answer
            case R.id.question_one_answer_two:
                if (checked) {
                    yourAnswerQ1 = Q1A2;
                    score++;
                    enableQuestion(Q1RadioGroup, false);
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.question_one_answer_three:
                if (checked) {
                    yourAnswerQ1 = Q1A3;
                    enableQuestion(Q1RadioGroup, false);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Checking which answer was selected - Question 2
     */
    public void onQ2AnswerEntered(View view) {
        question2Answer = Q2AnswerEditText.getText().toString();
        question2Answer = question2Answer.toLowerCase();

        if (question2Answer.equals("cosmo")) {
            //If the question is not empty, check if the answer is correct and add one point to the score
            //and display the score msg
            score++;
        }
        Q2AnswerEditText.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /*
     * Checking which answers were selected - Question 3
     */
    public void onCheckBoxesQ3Clicked(View view) {
        checkedQ3A1 = Q3A1.isChecked();
        checkedQ3A2 = Q3A2.isChecked();
        checkedQ3A3 = Q3A3.isChecked();

        if (checkedQ3A1 && checkedQ3A3) {
            score++;
        }

        // Check which checkbox button was checked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_four_answer_one:
                if (checkedQ3A1) {
                    yourAnswerQ3A1 = Q3A1;
                    enableQuestion(Q3A1, false);
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.question_four_answer_two:
                if (checkedQ3A2) {
                    yourAnswerQ3A2 = Q3A2;
                    enableQuestion(Q3A2, false);
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.question_four_answer_three:
                if (checkedQ3A3) {
                    yourAnswerQ3A3 = Q3A3;
                    enableQuestion(Q3A3, false);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }


    public void showScoreMessage(View view) {
        String scoreMessage = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.your_score_is), score);
        String customMessage = "";
        //To display a short message together with the score, according to what score the user got
        if (score == 0 || score == 1) {
            customMessage = "No soup for you!";
        } else if (score == 2) {
            customMessage = "Do a fit of strength and try again.";
        } else {
            customMessage = "You're a master of your domain.";
        }

        //Displaying the score message and the score
        Toast.makeText(this, scoreMessage + customMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void resetQuiz(View view) {
        //Enabling the questions
        enableQuestion(Q1RadioGroup, true);

        //Resetting questions: clearing the checked radio buttons and checkboxes
        Q1RadioGroup.clearCheck();

        //Resetting questions: Q3 - deleting the text in the EditText
        Q3AnswerEditText.setText("");
        Q3AnswerEditText.setEnabled(true);

        //if the checkboxes are checked, then uncheck and enable them
        if (checkedQ3A1) {
            Q3A1.setChecked(false);
            enableQuestion(Q3A1, true);
        }
        if (checkedQ3A2) {
            Q3A2.setChecked(false);
            enableQuestion(Q3A2, true);
        }
        if (checkedQ3A3) {
            Q3A3.setChecked(false);
            enableQuestion(Q3A3, true);
        }

        //Resetting the score variable
        score = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using android:enabled=false or editText.setEnabled(false)
It will grey out Edittext.

Comment: Thanks. I updated both the XML and the Java on the OP but now I have to click on the EditText twice (once to enter the answer and twice to have it grayed out). The problem with the score variable remains.
If I use the reset button, then the EditText will gray out before I can enter an answer.

Comment: Try adding android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for edittext